# Create video from audio with Xuggler

Tags: java, audio, video, xuggler

I'm trying to pragmatically create a video from an audio file (probably WAV). The video will be nothing fancy, just a few lines of text on a black background. It'll last the entirety of the audio clip and then save it to a file (ideally MP4).

My problem is that I'm not entirely sure where to start. Like, I've read the tutorials and whatnot but I still don't know where to start. I assume you need to create a reader, a writer, and a tool to place in the chain to put text on the screen. However, I don't know if you can just create images and Xuggler will automatically realize that it's dealing with a video file, not just an audio file. Also, I'm not sure how to load in an audio file in Xuggler.

Thank you for any help you're able to provide.